# Download and store file to Azure using Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I want to download file from some third party server and wanted to store inside Azure Storage. But I want to perform this process using Azure function. Below are the steps I want to achieve.

1. Create Azure(HTTP trigger enable)function what will be executed by third party server using WebHook.
2. Download file content using download URL given by Webhook using "Webclient" in C#.
3. Store file content into Azure Storage directly.

   ```
      
       Task.Run(() =>
       {
       using (var webClient = new WebClient())
       {
           webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, string.Format("Bearer {0}", {download token}));
           webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
           webClient.DownloadFileAsync("https://www.server.com/file1.mp4", {Here I want to store file into Azure Storage});
           }
           });
   ```

Comment: You can put the file in the request body of httptrigger, then create a blob and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the file in the request body of the req like this, and then upload it to azure blob storage.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //Here is the keycode.

            //Connect to the Storage Account.
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=bowmanimagestorage02;AccountKey=xxxxxxxfile.core.windows.net/");
            var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            //Here is the container name on portal.
            var container = myClient.GetContainerReference("test");

            //Here is the name you want to save as.
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("something.txt");

            //Put the stream in this place.
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(req.Body);


            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can also pass in the data stream, the key code is the same.

Comment: Thanks @BowmanZhu. While researching on internet, I read somewhere that we can directly associate storage account without writing code. Is it true or approach suggested by you is also a same thing?

Comment: @DharmeshSolanki Associated storage accounts are necessary, and the code I provided also requires an associated storage account. What do you mean by not having to use code? According to your description, you want to use Azure Function to upload files to Azure Storage, then you obviously need to write processing logic in Azure Function.

Comment: yes you are right but in sample code you are written code to find container, storage account, blob etc... that's why I asked like if we can do something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp

However I do not have much experience in Azure and code you provided will definitely help me to achieve what I wanted do.

Comment: @DharmeshSolanki Yes, Azure Function supports output binding for Storage blobs. But instead of blobtrigger, you should follow this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp

Comment: @DharmeshSolanki If my answer helped you, can you mark it as the answer to end this question?:)

Comment: means if I simply use [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] then will it be same thing to find container, storage and blob etc...?

Comment: @DharmeshSolanki Yes, similar to my code, you still need to provide those conditions, such as where you want to upload to, what storage account to connect to, etc. Check this out:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations

Comment: @DharmeshSolanki You need to provide the Connecting String of the Storage Account, and please note that you cannot directly put the value of the Connecting String into it. Fill in a key in the Connection section, and then configure the corresponding value in the environment variable configuration section (locally, the value of the environment variable is configured in local.settings.json. On Azure, please set it in the Configuration)